# Python return issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm writing a program that creates a file and then reads through it and prints the maximum and minimum value in the file and returns the average of all the values in the file. This is a homework assignment and my teacher asked specifically for the printing and returning differences so that's why those are there.

I got the program running smoothly and working just the way I want it to, but after i put my function at the end so it automatically runs when the shell is reset it messed up the end of my code and it won't return the average anymore. Before I put the function at the end and I did everything manually it worked like a charm. I was hoping you guys might be able to help me figure out why it's cutting the average out when I put my function at the end of the program. Thanks for taking the time to read through and help me out, I really appreciate it.

I realize there's probably a lot simpler ways I could've done this, but I'm fairly new with Python. All I'm really looking for is why it's cutting my average off in my results when I put my function in at the end.
Here's my code:

```
    def summaryStats():
        fileName = input("Enter a file name please: ")
        outputFile = open(fileName, "w")
        numberstoGenerate = int(input("Please enter how many units long you would like the list to be: "))
        while numberstoGenerate > 0:
            randomNumber = int(random.random()*1000)
            outputFile.write(str(randomNumber) + "\n")
            numberstoGenerate = numberstoGenerate - 1
        outputFile.close()
        file = open(fileName, "r")
        average = 0
        myList = file.readlines()
        myList = myList[0:]
        print("The maximum value is " + str(max(myList)))
        print("The minimum value is " + str(min(myList)))
        for element in myList:
            average = average + int(element)
        return average/len(myList)

    summaryStats()
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean, but if you were seeing the average but now you're not, have you tried changing it to `print summaryStats()`?

Comment: Sorry for the commentless code. My teacher is asking specifically for return to be used for the average. without summaryStats() at the end it works fine, but with it it only prints the maximum/minimum then stops.

Comment: Maybe your confusion is around the behavior of `return`?  Apologies if it's obvious, but this is returning a value to the caller, and in your example the caller does not do anything with it (it's effectively discarded).  The predecessor which has the desired behavior -- was this without a `def summaryStats()` but instead had everything at file scope and did `print average/len(myList)`?

Comment: That might be it, but I'm kind of confused by your response. I guess what I need it to do is return the average and without my summaryStats() at the end it does that. When I put summaryStats() at the end to make it run automatically when the shell resets suddenly it leaves the average out of my results. So I guess my confusion is lying in the summaryStats() causing my return to not actually return the value of average to me.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Raiyan helped point out my stupid mistake in that I had summaryStats() at the end in stead of print(summaryStats()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any line inside the function for printing the average value. You can either take the return value and print it:

```
result = summaryStats()
print result
```

or add a line in the function to print the average value.

Comment: Normally I would've just printed the average, but my teacher asked specifically for the average to be returned and not printed.

Comment: ok, so let me get this straight. You want to calculate the average (besides other things), then return it. You also want to print the average value printed. Right ?

Comment: Yes the average needs to be calculated and printed back to the user. With my code like it is it worked the way I wanted it to, but as soon as I put the summaryStats() at the end so it would run automatically on reset then the only things I get back are the maximum and minimum and it completely leaves the average out of the shell.

Comment: Can you post your shell script too ?

Comment: I need some clarification here. What do you mean by, "run automatically on reset" ?

Comment: Without summaryStats() at the end:
 The maximum value is 972.

 The minimum value is 106.

474.7
With summaryStats() at the end:
 The maximum value is 933.

 The minimum value is 10.

As you can see it leaves out the average. (These were both done with my file being 50 values long if that makes any difference.)

Comment: you're taking random numbers, so result should vary from one run to another. But I'm still not sure what you mean by "run automatically on reset" ??

Comment: Well I mean the purpose of the summaryStats() at the end is to automatically run my function when the shell is reset as opposed to manually entering summaryStats() in the shell each time.

Comment: well, like i said before, you have to take the return value (in a variable) then print it. Instead of just calling summaryStats(), try putting the two lines of code I posted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40792/discussion-between-tim-shaw-and-raiyan)